# Eccentricity of a hyperbola given the angle between the x-axis and its asymptote

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I need to find the eccentricity of a hyperbola whose asymptote makes an angle $\alpha$ with the $x$-axis.

So, I take the case where the transverse axis will be horizontal, $i.e.$

$\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}} - \frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}} = 1$

I note that $\tan(\alpha) = \frac{b}{a}$.

I need $\epsilon = \frac{a^2}{c}$, so I can get $a$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $b$, $i.e.$

$a^2 = \frac{b^2}{({tan\alpha})^2}$

by using the fact that the asymptote has equation $y=\frac{b}{a}x$  and ${tan\alpha} = \frac{b}{a}$

After this I get stuck.  I'm thinking that my solution must be in terms of $\alpha$ only, since I'm not given any information about $a$ or $b$.  And I know that $c^2 - a^2 = b^2$, but I'm not seeing the algebra necessary to properly substitute in so that the the eccentricity is represented only in terms of $\alpha$.

Am I on the right track, and, if so, where do I go from here?

I figure, once I have this case, I can easily make an analogous argument for a hyperbola with a vertical transverse axis.

Answer (score 1):

So $\tan\alpha = \frac{b}{a}$ and $c^2 - a^2 = b^2$

So we have:

$c^2 = a^2 + b^2$

$c^2 = a^2 + (a^2)tan^2\alpha$

$c = \sqrt{a^2 + (a^2)tan^2\alpha}$

$c = a\sqrt{1 + tan^2\alpha}$

$c = a\sqrt{sec^2\alpha}$

$c = (a)(sec\alpha)$

$\frac{c}{a} = sec\alpha$

$\epsilon = sec\alpha$